# Spring Boot Web Test - 404 Not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, testing

I am trying to test the Controller of a very simple GET request with @WebMvcTest  but I'm getting 404 instead of 200 and the console does not give me anything useful to understand what is going on.

I've put a breakpoint at the beginning of the controller but it never arrives. If I run the application, the endpoint works as expected.

Here's my controller:

```
@RestController
public class RegistroClienteController  {        

    @GetMapping("/api/registro-cliente")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> crearCliente() {
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And here's my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(RegistroClienteController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SecurityConfig.class })
public class RegistroClienteControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        mockMvc
            .perform(get("/api/registro-cliente"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
        //@formatter:on
    }
}
```

And console's output:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/registro-cliente
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = [[Cookie@624b3544 name = 'XSRF-TOKEN', value = 'f9d63654-4e21-4d41-b3bb-6767703268b5', comment = [null], domain = [null], maxAge = -1, path = '/', secure = false, version = 0, httpOnly = false]]
```

Comment: I ran your code without `SecurityConfig` and its working fine, I think your `SecurityConfig` is not getting loaded correctly and stopping to hit the controller from Unit Test method.

Comment: In my security config I have permitted all the URLs for this purpose. If I change this, and for example secure this URL, then the error is 401 (Unauthorized) which is ok.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same error and after hours of searching found that the error is due to controller not being registered. The problem is described [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15061).

Apparently, the following is not enough.

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {<ControllerToTest>.class})
```

You need to do,

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {<ControllerToTest>.class})
@Import(<ControllerToTest>.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

I can try to change the annotations

`@WebMvcTest(RegistroClienteController.class)`

to

`@SpringBootTest(classes = {your application class}.class)`